# VW Beetle Spaceship

Tags: story-identification, novel

In the late 60's/early 70's, I read a novel about aliens who came to help Earth. I remember only two details:

- They turned the coffee in the Pentagon green in an attempt to get people to take them seriously
- Their spaceship morphed into a VW Beetle.

Help! I would think I made up this plot, but my Mom remembers reading it as well.

Comment: This sounds pretty "far out man!"

Comment: Yeah, I'd never take anyone seriously who turned my coffee green. By the way, did the word "morph" even exist in the early 70s?

Answer (score 8):

*[Pandemonium on the Potomac](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13569483-pandemonium-on-the-potomac)* (1966) by William Charles Anderson.

[image: Book cover]

This fits both details in the question:

- The spaceship that morphs into a Volkswagen:

  > “And then you turned your spaceship into a Volkswagen.”
  >
  > “Oh yes. Straightaway. I had no desire to arouse curiosity by having
  >   the early light of dawn disclose a flying saucer parked on the dome of
  >   the monument.”
- And the green coffee:

  > “You mean all the coffee within a radius of a mile and a half is green
  >   this morning?”
  >
  > “Yes,” said Homer, his eyes shining. “Is that not most interesting?

Comment: Can you offer any confirming details from that book, ideally linking to a source?

Comment: Well, this is definitely it. I could add some text about the green coffee and the Volkswagon if the edit doesn’t go too far.

Comment: @Adamant - you should always feel free to edit in '*supporting quotes'* (e.g. those that bolster the answer rather than rewriting it).

Comment: @Valorum - Agreed, but I prefer to give the author a chance to edit first. Most of the time, I like to be cautious with edits.

Comment: @Adamant - I've never seen anyone complaining about the addition of a book quote or a single-sourced review.

Comment: I go back and forth on whether to wait on authors. Generally, I go ahead and edit in what's easy to find (Goodreads link, book cover, summary) and edit the rest of the stuff in a day or two later so that they don't get lazy and assume all they have to do is post a title. ^_^

Comment: @Fuzzyboots - Where did you get the quotes from?

Comment: @Valorum: I didn't. :) Adamant did.

Comment: @Valorum - From buying and reading the ebook.

Comment: @Adamant - Well, that's one way of doing it... :-)